# Can not receive signal from other thread in Qt for Android

Tags: android, qt

I have some code run on windows.When I run it on Android used `Qt for Android`.It seems can't emit signal to reach the slot in other thread.My code is below:

```
m_pSqlThread = new SqlThread();
m_pSqlThread->moveToOtherThread();

connect(m_pSqlThread, SIGNAL(innerresult(QSqlQueryEx*)),             this, SLOT(result(QSqlQueryEx*)));
connect(m_pSqlThread, SIGNAL(innererror(QSqlErrorEx,QSqlQueryEx*)),  this, SLOT(error(QSqlErrorEx,QSqlQueryEx*)));
connect(this,         SIGNAL(innerExec(QSqlQueryEx *)),             m_pSqlThread, SLOT(exec(QSqlQueryEx *)));
connect(this,         SIGNAL(threadInit()),                         m_pSqlThread, SLOT(init()));

emit threadInit();
```

`SqlThread` class is used to deal with block functions in other thread,I use

```
void SqlThread::moveToOtherThread()
{
    moveToThread(ThreadSingleton::getInstance());//ThreadSingleton::getInstance() get a QThread *
}
```

to move it in other thread.Now I emit `this->innerExec()`,It can reach the slot `exec()` in `m_pSqlThread`.

But when `m_pSqlThread` emit signal `innnerresult()` in `exec()`, the slot `this->result()` won't run.If I change the connect flag to `Qt::DirectConnection`.It works , but it's not I want you know.

So , I'm very interested in why the code run correct on Windows but on Android? Why `this` can emit signal successfully but `m_pSqlThread` can't?

**I compared the moc files generated by two compilers , there is no difference. And all connect returned true.**

P.S. I can't find `Qt for Android` tag...

---

**I found the cause:
If you use a global value out of the `main()` as receiver , it cannot receive the signal in Android mod!!!!!! It seems like a BUG**

Can anyone know why? Because the JNI?

---

I have reported a bug to Qt and I will keep track of it.

Comment: Can you show us the `SqlThread::moveToOtherThread()` definition?

Answer (score 0):

I report it at [here](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-39446)

They said:

> You created a QObject-based object before QCoreApplication. That's not supported. Move the creation of the object into the main() function.

Yeah, I knew it when I found what caused problem. So I change my code to prevent global init out of main() function. But the different behaviors between windows and Android also the IOS should be told to developer I think.

Comment: In the docs it states: [*Note that for QObjects that are created before QApplication, QObject::thread() returns zero. This means that the main thread will only handle posted events for these objects; other event processing is not done at all for objects with no thread. Use the QObject::moveToThread() function to change the thread affinity for an object and its children (the object cannot be moved if it has a parent).*](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/threads-qobject.html#per-thread-event-loop)

Comment: Ok. In your bug description you just stated that you moved the `other` class to a thread, not the `global` class.